# Codeigniter FTP Class no errors and not working as intended

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, ftp

So i'm trying to use the codeigniter FTP class, and I am trying to run the following code:

```
public function ftp()
{
    echo 'test1'; 
    $config['hostname'] = $this->config->item('ftp_hostname');
    $config['username'] = $this->config->item('ftp_username');
    $config['password'] = $this->config->item('ftp_password');
    $config['debug']  = $this->config->item('ftp_debug');

    $this->ftp->connect($config);

    $list = $this->ftp->list_files('/');

    print_r($list);

    $this->ftp->close();

    echo 'test2';       
}
```

When I visit the page I only get the message 'test1' and it does not list anything on the page. At first I thought it was an issue with my home server, however when checking phpinfo() it shows that ftp is an accepted protocol so surely it isn't a server issue? Anyway any help is appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you load le library FTP ?

```
$this->load->library('ftp');
```

If you already load the library, try to write the login information into the function for testing.

```
 $config['hostname'] = 'localhost';
 $config['username'] = 'LoginFTP';
 $config['password'] = 'passFTP';
 $config['port']     = 21;
 $config['passive']  = FALSE;
 $config['debug']  = TRUE;
```

I hope it will help you.